# Proving that a set is totally bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I wish to prove that $B:=\{x \in l^2:\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n|x_n|^2 \leq 1\}$ is totally bounded, that is $ \forall \epsilon >0, \exists \ x_1, ..., x_n$ such that $$B \subset \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}B(x_k,\epsilon).$$

Note that $l^2$ is the set of vectors whose 2-norm is finite.

This means that I need to show that for $y_k \in B$, 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} |y_k-x_k|^2 \leq \epsilon^2.$$

However, it is not clear to me how to find such numbers $x_k$; maybe I am missing some useful inequality.

Comment: Your indices are all over the place. Your definition of $B$ sums over $k$ and uses $n$ inside and you use lower indices both for indexing your finite list of approximating vectors and for the components of fixed vectors...

Comment: ... Moreover you don’t want to find *numbers* in $\mathbb N$ that do stuff but **vectors**

Comment: Choose $\epsilon>0$ and select $N$ so that ${1 \over \sqrt{N}} < {1 \over 2} \epsilon$. Now find a ${1 \over 2} \epsilon$-net for the elements of $B$ that satisfy $x_n = 0$ for $n \ge N$.